# Identical operator strange behaviour

Tags: php, operators, comparison-operators

Can anyone explain me this strange behaviour of the "identical" operator in php?

```
$any_integer_but_not_one = -1;

var_dump( !$any_integer_but_not_one === 1 ); // bool(false)
var_dump(  $any_integer_but_not_one !== 1 ); // bool(true)

$int_one = 1;

var_dump( !$int_one === 1 ); // bool(false)
var_dump(  $int_one !== 1 ); // bool(false)
```

I expected that these tests will always return the same results (`true-true` or `false-false`), but they do not.

I thought that `!x === y` and `x !== y` do the same thing, so what is the difference? Here I am talking **only** for the *identical* operator, not the *equal* one.
(Any other questions I found were about differences between *equality* and *identity*)

Comment: Arent they outputting the same thing? False False for the last twos

Comment: @Umair yes, but see the first two tests.

Comment: I thought the two operators `(! sth === sth )` and `( sth !== sth)` will return the same thing every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

its because -

`!$any_integer_but_not_one` will return `false`.

when `var_dump( !$any_integer_but_not_one === 1 );` it is `var_dump( false === 1 );`

so it will return `false`

Comment: I might start understaning what the problems is... It is something about the priority of the operators, right? You mean that `!` has higher priority than  `===`?

Comment: I totally forgot about the operator's priority, I thought that `!x === y` was the same as `!(x === y)`. I got it!

Comment: was my mistake.. forgot about `===`.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Maybe it's better to say that `!` has higher priority than `===`, so first `!x` is calculated and then `===`. Thanks!

Comment: no... its not actual priority.. `!` will alwasy return the opposite. `!==` is a different operator.dont mix `!$a == 1` and `$a !== 1`.

Comment: `not is identical` and `is not identical` sound me the same.